# 3rd party tool for log rotation in Linux?

Tags: linux, logging

I want an auto archive all of my log files for an application on my Linux distro.
Also after the log files have been archived,
the actual log files should be deleted (not the archived ones).
I know  almost all Linux distro have the utility 'logrotate'
and in logrotate.conf we can specify the log rotation, compress, options etc.

What I need is another 3rd party tool rather than 'logrotate'.
If I say I don't wanna use logrotate, 
is there any other tool that can accomplish this task???

Comment: What is the rationale behind this?  Btw, you could use a postrotate script within logrotate to ship files off to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Any backup tool can be used for archiving.

You might want to look into [`rsnapshot`](http://www.rsnapshot.org/). It is also available as Ubuntu [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rsnapshot) or as a [rpm package](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rsnapshot) for example.